# What is this object on my map?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, I was spectating and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to enlarge my map. A strange object appeared on my screen.

[The map:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovwsK.jpg)
[image: Map Overview]

The object in question:
[image: The object in question]

Around the object were white rings the expanded and eventually faded away. As one ring faded away, another smaller one formed around the object.

What is this? what does it represent?

Comment: Any custom HUDs?

Comment: @Fistosaur No, my copy of CS:GO is 100% vanilla.

Comment: This is on the minimap, correct? Best I would assume this is the bomb. Or, the more likely scenario is that it's a decoy grenade.

Comment: @Fistosaur It's on the enlargened mini-map. The bomb was somewhere else (and it looks different from this), and I highly doubt it's a decoy. I flew around in free-spectate mode and did not see any decoy grenade around the area. Plus, other decoy grenades didn't make that mark on my map. Such a mystery :O

Comment: @Fistosaur Yes. http://i.imgur.com/BeZpbVx.jpg The bleep is towards the left of the map. There is a black square used to block someone's name for privacy reasons.

Comment: @avestar101 I'm going to delete some of my comments, but I updated your question to be a little more informational

Comment: Is it **only** on this map?  Is it **always** on this map?

Comment: @Batophobia I can recall seeing something like this before on another map. It's definitely not always on the map. Also, the server was an official Valve server.

Comment: When it does happen, is it there from the beginning of the match?  Does it last the whole game?

Comment: @Batophobia I don't remember that much, but I *think* it wasn't there from the start of the game. I'm not sure whether or not it lasted the entire game. It *may* have been the last round

Comment: @PhilippM If only Valve could simply tell us :P

Comment: @avestar101 I think I found the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

That is a **decoy** grenade.

This symbol is only seen, when you're spectating. Obviously when you are playing you see only a symbol of an enemy on the map.